# literal `0` being a valid candidate for int and const string& overloads causes ambiguous call

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous-call

I fixed a bug recently.

In the following code, one of the overloaded function was const and the other one was not. The issue will be fixed by making both functions const.

My question is why compiler only complained about it when the parameter was 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CppSyntaxA
{
public:
    void f(int i = 0) const { i++; }
    void f(const std::string&){}
};

int main()
{
    CppSyntaxA a;
    a.f(1);  // OK
    //a.f(0);  //error C2666: 'CppSyntaxA::f': 2 overloads have similar conversions
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NeilButterworth GCC shows the [same behavior](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01aa5e86ec208c9c).

Comment: @Miles No, it doesn't.

Comment: @NeilButterworth sure does: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mEtMFPt5KMdSVGs3 and https://wandbox.org/permlink/8UiG8XD7d0ol8U8v

Comment: `clang` seems happy with it for what that's worth.

Comment: Obviously, I can't illustrate the lack of an error message, but GCC 8.1.0 compiles it with both -std=c++11 and -std=c++17

Comment: @NeilButterworth Try compiling with `-pedantic`

Comment: @eerorika I always do.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ If there's no diagnostic message, then I suppose it's a bug in that version of GCC.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`0` is special in C++.  A null pointer has the value of `0` so C++ will allow the conversion of `0` to a pointer type.  That means when you call

```
a.f(0);
```

You could be calling `void f(int i = 0) const` with an `int` with the value of `0`, or you could call `void f(const std::string&)` with a `char*` initialized to null.

Normally the `int` version would be better since it is an exact match but in this case the `int` version is `const`, so it requires "converting" `a` to a `const CppSyntaxA`, where the `std::string` version does not require such a conversion but does require a conversion to `char*` and then to `std::string`.  This is considered enough of a change in both cases to be considered an equal conversion and thus ambiguous.  Making both functions `const` or non `const` will fix the issue and the `int` overload will be chosen since it is better.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think f(int) is const and `a` is a non-const variable. So there is a cast from non-const to const.

Comment: @NeilButterworth fixed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Never noticed that `const`. Good observation and excellent answer. Edit : I guess I missed the part of the question that mentions it, must have skipped straight to the code...

Comment: For reference, the rules for determining the best overload can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) but I personally find them extremely hard to navigate. Edit : It seems that as far as the `const`ness of the function goes, member functions ares treated as if they had an additional implicit `this` argument. So non-`const` to `const` counting as an implicit conversion makes sense.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Don't worry, compiler implementers do as well ;)

Comment: "A null pointer has the value of 0" - Well, not *quite*. `nullptr` is its own distinct type (`std::nullptr_t`) (which can sometimes be important). It's *convertible* to `0`, but that's not the same thing as *being* `0`. The `NULL` macro just shouldn't be used. You already know this..

Comment: @JesperJuhl A null pointer, and `nullptr` are different things.  A [null pointer is an integer with the value of `0`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr#1.sentence-1) along with also being a prvalue of `nullptr_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I bow to the standards quote.  You are technically correct - the best kind of correct.

Comment: The most infuriating part of this overload issue is that it's UB to call the constructor of `std::string` with a null pointer :/

Comment: A null pointer has the value `0`? That's a new one. It's implementation-defined what value it has, though as literal `0` can be implicitly converted to any null pointer type, it therefore will compare equal. `(intptr_t)(void*)0 == 0` is not guaranteed, though holds on (most?) modern platforms. @JesperJuhl Seems you got off-track with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 11):

> My question is why compiler only complained about it when the parameter was 0.

Because 0 is not only an integer literal, but it is also a null pointer literal. 1 is not a null pointer literal, so there is no ambiguity.

The ambiguity arises from the implicit converting constructor of `std::string` that accepts a pointer to a character as an argument.

Now, the identity conversion from int to int would otherwise be preferred to the conversion from pointer to string, but there is another argument that involves a conversion: The implicit object argument. In one case, the conversion is from `CppSyntaxA&` to `CppSyntaxA&` while in other case it is `CppSyntaxA&` to `const CppSyntaxA&`.

So, one overload is preferred because of one argument, and the other overload is preferred because of another argument and thus there is no unambiguously preferred overload.

> The issue will be fixed by making both functions const.

If both overloads are `const` qualified, then the implicit object argument conversion sequence is identical, and thus one of the overloads is unambiguously preferred.